# How can I keep Views outside of ListView from being inflated?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I'm relatively new to Android dev so please pardon me if this is a basic question. I have a ListActivity which shows a progress bar when loading info and then gets hidden. However, every row of the listview beneath it draws has its own progressbar in it. How can I prevent this from happening? I've found a few somewhat similar questions but no working answer.
EDIT: This is resultslist.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/results_list_progress_bar"/>

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_below="@id/results_list_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/result_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/result_icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/result_title"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/result_icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

for what it's worth, here's the code from my array adapter:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resultslist, parent, false);
```

Here's an image, showing the progress bar at the top of each row:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What's this, `R.layout.resultslist`? Can you post that code?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry. resultslist.xml is the xml above. I'll edit that to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are inflating the same `activity view` as your `list item view`, check your view for the adapter

as of your update, it is visible that your are in fact inflating the same view

solution:

your main xml view (put this inside a linear layout):

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/results_list_progress_bar"/>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_below="@id/results_list_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

your list item view (put this inside a linear layout):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/result_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/result_icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result_description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/result_title"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/result_icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are doing is inflating the same layout for your `ListView` as you are for your activity. What that means is that every item in your `ListView` will have a `ProgressBar` and a `ListView` in addition to all the other things you want. What you should do is move these items:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/result_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/result_icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/result_title"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/result_icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

into a new layout, let's call it `listviewlayout.xml`. Then you change your code in your activity to this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewlayout, parent, false);
```

And then you keep the other stuff in your first layout.

Comment: Heh, yeah, I didn't realize that the layout which gets inflated is seperate from the activity layout. Thanks!